# How to clear gridview after generating pdf

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, pdf-generation

I have a project where I want to generate a PDF from gridview but after generating Pdf I want to refresh my gridview and add new data.

```
private void Generate_PDF()
            {

                     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                     HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

                        //Generate Invoice (Bill) Header.
                        sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Bill Report</b></td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Bill No: </b>");
                        sb.Append(HiddenField1.Value);
                        sb.Append("</td><td align = 'right'><b>Date: </b>");
                        sb.Append(DateTime.Now);
                        sb.Append(" </td></tr>");


                        sb.Append("</table>");
                        sb.Append("<br />");
                        GridOfTestRequest.RenderControl(hw);

                        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                        StringReader sr1 = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                        sb1.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                        sb1.Append("<tr><td align = 'right' colspan = '");
                        sb1.Append(GridOfTestRequest.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1);
                        sb1.Append("'>Total</td>");
                        sb1.Append("<td>");
                        sb1.Append(testList.Sum(x=>x.testFee));
                        sb1.Append("</td>");
                        sb1.Append("</tr></table>");


                        StringReader sr2 = new StringReader(sb1.ToString());
                        testList.Clear();
                        GridOfTestRequest.DataSource = null;
                        GridOfTestRequest.DataBind();
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A5, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr1);
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr2);

                        pdfDoc.Close();

                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoic.pdf");
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                        Response.Write(pdfDoc);

                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Cookies.Clear();

                        Response.End();



            }
```

After execution of this method in a button click, I want to clear the Gridview. How can I do it? I tried to clear it with `gridview.datasource=null` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Response.End(); will end all the communication to the client and any changes on server will not reflect at client until client does not refresh page.

Comment: Is there any way to do it? I have to clear it as my specification expect it. I have write my Clear method before Response.end but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Resolution: For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.

Comment: Still i have same problem. I have to refresh my page otherwise it doesn't work. But your code is working as it bypass for rest of request execution and Clear method executed now. Thanks .